# jQuery Document Ready - Is it best to wrap each statement or just wrap all statements in one document.ready event?

Tags: jquery, document-ready

I have seen it both ways, but which is better or does it not matter.

I feel as though wrapping each statement might be cleaner, but just wondering if its more callbacks if you have 50 statements each with their own document.ready event handler?

Comment: My preference is to place it all in one for readability at least.

Comment: Why would you want to wrap every statement? That does seem like a lot more to write...

Answer (score 4):

There is a temptation among jQuery developers to hook everything into the `$(document).ready` pseudo event. After all, it is used in most examples you will find.

Although `$(document).ready` is incredibly useful, it occurs during page render while objects are still downloading. If you notice your page stalling while loading, all those `$(document).ready` functions could be the reason why.

You can reduce CPU utilization during the page load by binding your jQuery functions to the $(window).load event, which occurs after all objects called by the HTML (including  content) have downloaded.

Read more about jQuery performance and best practices [here](http://www.artzstudio.com/2009/04/jquery-performance-rules/) or [watch this video](http://yuilibrary.com/theater/john-resig/resig-testing/)